# Qt global style sheet loading?

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

How can I load a style sheet (.qss style resource) globally with Qt?

I am trying to make things a bit more efficient than:

```
middleIntText -> setStyleSheet("QLineEdit {  border: 1px solid gray;
                                border-radius: 5px;padding: 0 8px;
                                selection-background-color:darkgray;
                                height:40px;font-size:15px;}");
```

I thought the following would work at loading QLineEdit the one time for all QLineEdit widgets:

*qss file:*

```
QLineEdit {     border: 1px solid gray;
                border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 0 8px;
                selection-background-color:darkgray;
                height:40px;
                font-size:15px;}
```

*cpp file:*

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
QFile stylesheet("formStyle.qss");
stylesheet.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString setSheet = QLatin1String(stylesheet.readAll());
a.setStyleSheet(setSheet);
```

Perhaps this is right and I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: I have been talking to some guys over in the [Qt Forums](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19124/) and believe I may know what I need to do.  Report back tomorrow with a solution. It can basically be the file location of .qss, css syntax or just picking the right object to cascade down (ie. QMainWindow::setStyleSheet(QString)).  The method above should work once I figure which one of the three.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You called [QStyle * QApplication::setStyle ( const QString & style )](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#setStyle-2) which requests a QStyle object for *style* from the QStyleFactory.

Instead, you should call [void QApplication::setStyleSheet ( const QString & sheet )](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop) which sets the application style sheet.

Comment: You are correct.  Although this make no change, but I have changed the above code to reflect this part in the correct syntax.  I posted a comment below my question regarding the assumed answers.  I should have the actual answer tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

The above attempt is correct syntax but there are reasons it may not work.

**Possible problems:**

1. Source file(.qss) is not being retrieved
2. Incorrect top widget being chosen to apply cascade.
3. Syntax of the .qss (CSS) code.

Reason I had to ask my question above is I had two of these three issues.  I first had to point to the files correct location and second I had to apply directly to QWidget.

```
QFile stylesheet("G:/Applications/Projects/ProspectTracker/formStyle.qss");
stylesheet.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QString setSheet = QLatin1String(stylesheet.readAll());
QWidget::setStyleSheet(setSheet);
```

@Bill  Thank for your assistance.  He pointed out that I had posted `.setStyle` and not `.setStyleSheet`. The sample code above no longer reflects this but if I didn't change that nothing I did would have worked.