# Qt global css stylesheet?

Tags: c++, css, qt, qt5, qt5.7

In Qt, it is possible to use a subset of html and css to style (for example) QLabels:

```
QLabel label = new QLabel("This link will be colored: "<a style='color:#00aeef;' href='http://www.example.com'>link</a>.");
```

**My question:**

Is it possible to use a global stylesheet that makes all links in all QLabels colored or do I have to add the inline style to *every* link in *every* label?

**Note**

As far as I know, the style I want to change cannot be modified (as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681943/qt-global-style-sheet-loading)) with [QApplication::setStyleSheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#styleSheet-prop). I want to change the style of [embedded HTML markup](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html), but *setStyleSheet* only modifies styles of [QT Objects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) (no "a href" element anywhere on this page).

Comment: I clarified my question, it is no duplicate as far as I can see...

Comment: Fixed. You can look at [paletterole](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#paletterole) and [const QBrush &QPalette::link() const](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpalette.html#link)